# Parallel execution of a command on few boxes over ssh (using bash)

Tags: bash, ssh

What would be the cleanest way to execute same command remotely on several boxes with joint output to console?

For instance, I would like to tail logs from several boxes all together in my console as one output.

Comment: If you're asking how to do this from an interactive command line, that's a better fit for [unix.se] than here. StackOverflow's scope is limited to *software development*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely [`GNU parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is a nice tool for parallelizing things in the shell. It also has reasonable [remote execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Remote-execution) capabilities.

It can be as easy as

```
parallel -S $SERVER1 -S $SERVER2 echo ::: running on more hosts
```

Comment: Running `parallel --tag` is useful here. Also, you can add servers using commas, `-S $SERVER1,$SERVER2,$SERVER3`

Comment: For `tail -f` you should also have a look at `--line-buffer`